# ArcMap Python Maplex labeling

Tags: arcgis-desktop, labeling, python-parser, maplex

I'm doing Maplex-Python labels for municipality polys with yields positive, zeroes and null values. I want to label all municipality polys by their municipality name, however I don't want to display yield labels for municipality polys with zero or null yield values. E.g. Bighorn and Ranchland have zero yield values and so yield values aren't labeled but their municipality name is labeled. However, my "else:" labels don't seem to plot municipality names - polys with "null" values - unnamed polys left to Bighorn and above Ranchland. What am I doing wrong?

```
def FindLabel ( [fcastyld.WH_D_L], [fcastyld.WH_D_H], [fcastyld.WH_D_A], [municipalities.NAME] ):
  if long([fcastyld.WH_D_A]) > 0:
    label = "L" + [fcastyld.WH_D_L] + "H" + [fcastyld.WH_D_H] + "A" + [fcastyld.WH_D_A] + "\n" + "<FNT name='Arial Narrow' size='5'><ITA><CLR red='104' green='104' blue='104'>" + [municipalities.NAME]  + "</CLR></ITA></FNT>"
  else:
    label = "<FNT name='Arial Narrow' size='5'><ITA><CLR red='104' green='104' blue='104'>" + [municipalities.NAME] + "</CLR></ITA></FNT>"
  return label
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you paste your code as text and apply 'format code' to it please. I suspect you need a condition *if [blah.blah] is None:* branch first before *if long([blah.blah]) > 0:* to catch the Null values.

Comment: I've tried to add the formatted code.

Comment: Are the values Null because there is no matching row in the join table or because the matching row has a Null value?

Comment: Yes values are null because there are no matching row in the join table.

Comment: That can be difficult.. it's one of the many flavors of nothing but is hard to apply because the value is ethereal. Can you permanently join the attributes in the table using Join Field http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//001700000065000000 to make the Null value firm?

Comment: No... in our mapping process we set-up the .mxd and layers and symbology and setup field joins and simply replace the .dbf file to do the join to create biweekly maps. Do you suggest I do a definition query for municpal polys with null values as labeling layer? Is there a way - i.e. if [fcastyld.WH_D_A]): return municipal name as label, else: return concatenated label?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/64209/discussion-between-michael-stimson-and-arun-govind).

Answer (score 2):

After a quick test:

```
def FindLabel (  [JoinTest.Grid]  ):
    if [JoinTest.Grid] == None:
        lab = 'No Match'
    else:
        lab = 'Matched'
    return lab
```

With a joined table I can say safely that `join.field == None` is a valid condition as at ArcGIS 10.2.1. To catch non-matched rows and label as if the value is 0 you can use this python code:

```
def FindLabel ( [fcastyld.WH_D_L], [fcastyld.WH_D_H], [fcastyld.WH_D_A], [municipalities.NAME] ):
    if [fcastyld.WH_D_A] == None:
        label = "<FNT name='Arial Narrow' size='5'><ITA><CLR red='104' green='104' blue='104'>" + \
                        [municipalities.NAME] + "</CLR></ITA></FNT>"
    elif long([fcastyld.WH_D_A]) > 0:
        label = "L" + [fcastyld.WH_D_L] + "H" \
                        + [fcastyld.WH_D_H] + "A" + [fcastyld.WH_D_A] + "\n" + \
                        "<FNT name='Arial Narrow' size='5'><ITA><CLR red='104' green='104' blue='104'>" + \
                        [municipalities.NAME]  + "</CLR></ITA></FNT>"
    else:
        label = "<FNT name='Arial Narrow' size='5'><ITA><CLR red='104' green='104' blue='104'>" + \
                        [municipalities.NAME] + "</CLR></ITA></FNT>"
    return label
```

The `\` between lines are continuation characters to extend the string to the next line, for readability, they can be safely removed if they cause problems.

Comment: I've another issue Michael, can you please check our discussion board from yesterday?